# BIGQUERY: Select and replace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm very new to bigquery and I am looking to run a query which selects every row from a table where touch_by_bot is false. I then want to replace these same row values with true.

I figured out how to pull the rows that are false but I can't figure out how to replace the false values with true:

'SELECT * FROM `...` WHERE touched_by_bot = false'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select * replace(true as touched_by_bot) from ... where touched_by_bot = false
```

or updating the table itself.

```
create temp table your_table as 
select false as touched_by_bot union all
select true;

update your_table set touched_by_bot = true where touched_by_bot = false;

select * from your_table;
```

Comment: Hi Jaeseok! This works amazingly for changing the data pulled. Is there any way I can update the values in the table itself so when I call the same query again it will only pull the ones that haven't been changed to true?

Comment: Essentially, I'm using the BigQuery API in Apps Script to pull from a table that is constantly being added to. I only want my apps script to pull rows that it has not processed before

Comment: maybe you can use **UPDATE** query to do that.